# How to find set of corresponding string patterns in java?

Tags: java

I have a  string

```
             "yes 12 /12 /yes /n
              yes 12 /12 /yes "
```

How do I check that whenever I have "yes" in the string, I have a corresponding "/yes" and similarly, whenever I have "12", I have a corresponding "/12"?
For example, if the string as

```
             "yes 12 /12 /yes /n 
              yes 12 /12 "
```

It should give me an error saying error in line 2, and then move on reading the rest of the file.

Comment: Is this an acceptable input? `yes 12 /yes /12` (so is it requred that the input is in well-formed like when using parentheses, or not?)

Comment: Do you want that for just 12 and yes? What have you tried?

Comment: Using regex and backreferences? `[A-Za-z0-9]*? \\\1` or something perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

use `String.contains()` method

```
String s= "yes 12 /12 /yes /n"
if(s.contains("yes") && s.contains("/yes")){
   sysout("yes");
}
```

do the same thing for any other pair :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get a list of all words. Then for each word, try to see if /word is contained.

```
String s = "12 a /12";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s"));
for (String value : list) {
  if (list.contains("/" + value)) {
    System.out.println("Does contain");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Doesn't contain");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method in [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class:

```
String str = ""yes 12 /12 /yes /n";
boolean isOk = str.contains("yes") && str.contains("/yes"); // isOk = true

str = "yes 12 /12 ";
isOk = str.contains("12") && str.contains("/12") // isOk = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some recursion to find the tags and the corresponding closing tag:

```
public class TagMatching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("yes 12 /12 /yes /n",
                                           "yes 12 /12 /yes",
                                           "yes 12 a b /12 /yes",
                                           "yes 12 c /12 /yes");
        for (String line : lines) {
            boolean valid = validate(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
            System.out.println("valid = " + valid);
        }
    }

    public static boolean validate(List<String> tags) {
        if (tags.size() == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        String first = tags.get(0);
        String last = tags.get(tags.size() - 1);
        if (last.equals("/" + first)) {
            return validate(tags.subList(1, tags.size()-1));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```